# Using Google Maps for iOS with device 12.x

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using Google maps for ios, needing to update my libraries (I use maps 2.0), I've downloaded the new API - 8.0.0 - Unfortunately this update broken the app with ios < 13.
We use XCode with Objective-C++
I tried to download a previous version (to get my app continue working with these ios), but I can't find it.
Where I could find to download previous versions (6.2.1 - 7.4.0)?
What is the right version to continue support these ios version?

Many thanks to all.